# Manual scale dialog in edit mode

Tags: scale

The manual scale dialog seems to be missing when I'm in edit mode.  What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: There is no manual scale dialog in edit mode on that panel, you can enable scale manipulator clicking on the icon with 3 axis on the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  So am i wrong to want that?  I'm trying to scale precisely, and when I use the manipulator it has to interpolate and jumps between essentially random numbers.  ie. from say 70.34 to 72.65 when I move a single pixel.  Is there another (more correct) way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to hit the **S key** and followed by a  number it will change the scale to it in edit mode

S + .5 or S + 2.5 etc

The menu you are looking for is not available in Edit mode

**Edit Mode:**
[image]
Object Mode:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response.  It's not the buttons that are missing, but the manual dialogs.  See the square I drew on my screenshot.

Comment: Please take a look of updated answer, if it worked please accept the answer

Comment: Thank you for accepting the answer, you may also vote it up for me, as presently its showing negative :( Have a nice Time!!

Comment: i tried but it says i don't have karma enough yet :-/

Comment: Ok, no problem, Thanks for your support :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no manual scale panel in Edit mode, only in Object mode. Vertices don't really have a specific scale—when you scale them up or down, it's a one-shot action. So it doesn't really make sense to have a manual scale box—when you weren't editing it, it would always display 1.